# App MEAN desplegada intenta conectarse al local de la computadora que hace la peticion

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, digitalocean

Desplegue una app MEAN en digitalOcean, puedo acceder a la pagina web que esta en la carpeta siendo servida desde la carpeta public, cuando intento hacer peticiones a la api desde la webpage no llega nunca la peticion (veo esto con morgan), pero al momento de levantar el server desde mi pc de una vez la recibe y permite su correcto funcionamiento. (en local funciona todo correctamente), si hago las peticiones al server desde postman apuntando al api funciona.

configure el nginx de la siguiente manera:

```
    location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
```

de esta manera incluyo los controllers

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu servidor en DO esta apuntando a localhost?

Comment: si te refieres a la app si apunta entonces si, en el objeto environment tengo seteado esto

Comment: Pero localhost es al navegador donde se esta ejecutando... vos deberias apuntar a tu servidor de api en DO... localhost es donde esta el navegador....

Comment: aaah ok, muchas gracias cuando yo habia desplegado angular antes en heroku no tuve que hacer eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: porque tal vez no tenias un backend?

Comment: si tenia un backend siempre habia desplegado de igual manera en heroku-

Comment: con localhost? raro...

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la capa 8, graicas @gbianchi que me dijo que pusiera la ip del server en el environment de angular y no el localhost.